# Xcode, HMSoft HM-10 BLE connect to one module directly without choosing UUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hm-10

ive bought some HM-10 Modules to talk to Arduino with an iOS-App.
Ive tried the examples and they worked but in every app you have to choose the device to talk to.
My plan is to control an RGB-Light with that modules and the code already works on the arduino-side.
Ive changed the tutorial-apps so talking with these to the arduino is possible too.
So i need help how to connect directly to the module-uuid without all the errorhandling-stuff and TableView. The only errorhandling i need would be "Device not found" if its not available. Im kinda new to xcode and ios-programming and have a lack of skills at the moment but the internet was not very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is a little general.  But I've written a full tutorial on the matter.

"[Connect an Arduino to your iPhone](https://ladvien.com/connect-an-arduino-to-iphone/)"

I wrote it more as a journal of my learning experience, as I had never used a Mac or Xcode.  It's not too hard.

Do know, many of the major iOS apps I've found don't like the HM-10.  The one exception being LightBlue.  I believe this is due to the advertising interval, which can now be changed with in the HM-10 firmware.  Good luck.

Comment: Your link does not lead to your tutorial anymore... where can we find your tutorial?